# Exception when I initialize a map with a vector layer in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, openlayers-3

I'm trying to add an icon on an OpenLayers 3 map but I noticed my code doesn't work in IE 8.

Here's my code :

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    //create empty vector
});

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([longitude,lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
        name: 'Null Island ',
        population: 4000,
        rainfall: 500
    });
    vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);

    //create the style
    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
            anchor: [0.5, 46],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            opacity: 0.75,
            src: 'http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/data/icon.png'
        }))
    });

    //add the feature vector to the layer vector, and apply a style to whole layer
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: iconStyle
    });

    map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
            vectorLayer
        ],
        view: new ol.View2D({
            center: ol.proj.transform([longitude, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 12
        }),
        target: 'map'
    });
```

There's no exception when I don't use `vectorlayer` during the map initialization but the map is centered about 30km beside where it should be and the zoom effect doesn't work well.

The exception is at the line 2421 of the uncompressed ol.js. `goog.asserts.ENABLE_ASSERTS` equals `true`

```
goog.asserts.fail = function(opt_message, var_args) {
  if(goog.asserts.ENABLE_ASSERTS) {
    throw new goog.asserts.AssertionError("Failure" + (opt_message ? ": " + opt_message : ""), Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  }
};
```

**Question 1**

Does OpenLayers 3 supports IE 8?

On the [website](http://openlayers.org/) they mention that they support less capable browsers

> promises to bring 3D capabilities and increased performance for all
>   mapping needs to the latest browsers. OpenLayers 3.0 will offer WebGL,
>   while degrading nicely in less capable browsers.

**Question 2**

Is there an easy fix to avoid that exception. I don't really mind about the zoom effect as long as the icon shows up at the good place.

I use the F12 tool in IE for my tests and I set the document mode and the user agent string to IE 8

Thank you

Comment: Reading this thread, http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.devel.ol3/952, I suspect not. IE8 does not support SVG or webGL and it looks like a decision has been made that older version of IE are too much of a drain on limited dev resources.

Comment: Thank you John, I guess I will have to make a decision. Since bootstrap supports IE8 I thought I would but now I'm not sure. I don't know if I should downgrade to Openlayers 2 to support IE8. I will have to read about OpenLayers 3 new features compared to the previous version. Thank you, you can write your comment as an answer.

Comment: Marc, extended my comment as an answer. Sorry, it isn't a very positive one in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading this thread, http://boundlessgeo.com/2012/06/visions-for-openlayers-3/, written by one of the main OpenLayers developers, it sounds like there was the intention to support DOM based rendering for older browsers. However, reading this one, http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.devel.ol3/952, or this one, http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.devel.ol3/984,  posted over a year later,  it sounds like that is no longer the case because of versions of IE before 9 not supporting SVG/Canvas.

In OpenLayers 2, IE support for older browsers is done via VML and is one of the only parts of the code base where there is browser detection. I grepped the OL3 code base and there is no mention of VML, which would rule out any polygon rendering in IE versions less than 9.

OpenLayers 3 is a clean break from OpenLayer 2 and it is reasonable that development effort is being focussed on webGL renderers and 3D capabilities in an open source development environment, without unlimited funds. OpenLayer 2 will continue to work in future browsers and  as it has a large install and a non-trivial upgrade path, will probably survive for some time.

Ultimately, you will probably get the best answer from the OpenLayers mailing list or on #openlayers.

Comment: Marc, if you find out any more information from irc or mailing list, could you update my answer. I suspect a number of people will have this question in the coming months, as OL3 gets ready for full release. We still have a few clients using IE7, amazingly.